# What double negation does in C

Tags: c

I had a controversy about what compilers "think" about this:

```
a = 8;
b = !!a;
```

So, is `b == 0x01` ? Is `TRUE` always `0x01` or it may be `0xFF`, `0xFFFF`, `0xFFFFFFFF` etc..?

If I want to extract only `0x00` if `(a == 0)` and  `0x01` if `(a > 0)` does this double negation approach works?

In other words: to obtain result only 0 or 1, what is better to use?

a)  `a>0?1:0;`
b)  `!!a`

I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Duplicate did not address the tail end of the question; reopened.

Comment: Leave such optimizations to the compiler. Write the code which is the most readable to you.

Comment: If you want to "extract `0x01`" if `a > 0`, then these approaches are equivalent iff `a` is unsigned, or signed but always guaranteed to hold non-negative values. But I don't see you say that anywhere. In general, `a > 0` and `!!a` are not the same. So which one do you really need?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But maybe such code is more readable for him - you never know. Also there are the obfuscation code contests.

Comment: I'd say converting to  `bool`/`_Bool` is much better than those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!a` will be either 0 or 1, and will be type `int`. It will be 0 for zero `a`, and 1 otherwise.

As for your choices (a) and (b), they are **not** equivalent, due to a possibility of `a` being negative. That aside, you could argue that `a > 0 ? 1 : 0` is clearer but in performance-critical applications `!!a` may be better as it will not branch whereas a ternary conditional could dump the pipeline. But a good compiler will optimise out either way. I seldom use either since things like `if (a)` and `if (!!a)` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @arif (and bathsheba) http://goo.gl/RpznmQ Try to find a compiler in that list which produces different code for the two possibilities (Obviously, `a > 0 ? 1 : 0` will produce different code unless `a` is unsigned.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `b == 1`.  The result of any boolean operator is always 0 or 1.  You can do better though...

> I want to extract only 0x00 if (a == 0) and  0x01 if (a > 0)

`b = a > 0;` most accurately reflect your rule.

Comment: The **output** of any boolean operator is 0 or 1.  In the example of `a == -1`, `a` and `-1` are inputs to the operator, but the result will be `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 5):

You have not supplied enough information to tell whether `!!a` works for your purposes or not.

You stated that you really need the result of `a > 0`. However, this is not equivalent to `!!a` if `a` is signed and holds a negative value. If this is possible, then the answer is obviously "no".

`!!a` is equivalent to `a != 0`, not to `a > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`. C11 §6.5.3.3 5

`b` below will typical have the value of 1 (or possible -1, see below).

```
a = 8;
b = !!a;
```

> So, is `b == 0x01`?

Yes (* see below)

> Is `TRUE` always `0x01` or it may be `0xFF`, `0xFFFF`, `0xFFFFFFFF` etc..?

In `<stdbool.h>`, `true` is a macro with the integer constant 1. `TRUE` is not defined by the C standard.  Various implementations defines it with the value of 1.  It *might* be have other values.  It certainly should be non-zero.

> what is better to use?

```
A)  a>0?1:0 
B)  !!a
```

Both result in an `int` with the value of `0` or `1`. A reasonable to good compiler would be expected to generate the same code for both (if `a` in not signed).  Use the form that 1) adhere to your groups coding standard or else 2) best conveys the meaning of code at that point.  A third option which results in type `(bool)`:

```
C)  (bool) a
```

If `a` is signed , then `a>0?1:0` is not equivalent to `!!a`.  `a != 0 ? 1 :0` is equivalent of `!!a`.

---

`*` If `b` is a 1 bit signed bit field, `b = !!8` will have the value of -1.

Answer (score 0):

In teems of speed I think this is highly dependent on the compiler and processor you are using.

The longer expression would produce an executable 4 - 16 bytes larger.

Comment: On what compiler will the executable differ in size?