# What is the purpose of using the negation operator twice in C?

Tags: c

I saw the assert macro implementation which is this:

```
#define assert(_Expression) (void) ((!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression),_CRT_WIDE(__FILE__),__LINE__),0))
```

I don't understand the purpose of using the negation operator twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617090/double-negation-in-c-is-it-guaranteed-to-return-0-1 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847237/what-double-negation-does-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It converts an integer value into a `bool` value (although any non-zero integer value is implicitly `true` is does not have that formal value).

Comment: @TomKarzes The C standard refers to `!` as "logical negation operator", so it is not wrong.

Comment: You'll see this in JS and other more weakly-typed languages quite frequently as well.

Comment: @user21290559,  "don't understand the purpose of using the negation operator twice." --> If code had only 1 `!`, like `!(_Expression)`, would the purpose of the `!` make sense?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, if _Expression was true, then it's value would be reversed to become false which is zero. I didn't understand the purpose of switching the value to false and back to true again but I understand now thanks to the other comments.

Comment: @user21290559 "...and back to true again " is the error in logic.  The original value was not certainly only _true_ or _false_.  It could have been 0.1, a value outside the `int` range, complex, ...  With `!!` the result is an `int` with a value of 0 or 1.